# How to set access rights for lighttpd using python scripts (cgi) which uses temporary files

Tags: python, lighttpd

My problem is: I have a running lighttpd web server. The files are stored 
in \var\www, also a python script, which can be executed to get an image 
from the raspi camera. Every time the script is called, one image should
be delivered to the browser.

The lighttpd itself seems to work, I can see my web page from the browser,
I also can execute the phyton script (snap.py). But I get only ONE image
from the server. The web server executes the script, the script creates
a temporary /run/shm/img.jpg. this image is then delivered by the web server. 
The web server runs on a user "www-data". I can see that the image in /run/shm
is owned by "root" and not by "www-data". And this seems to be the problem.

Once this image is created, all later calls of the script cannot delete the
temp. image to create a new one.

I currently have no idea why a web server running with "www-data" access rights
creates files bolonging to "root", which later cannot be deleted any more..

I'm using this script on 2 older raspis (older installations). There this 
script runs fine , but now on a new installation I have this problem...

Can anyone help ?

This is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import subprocess
import os
import ftplib
import time
import smtplib
import Image
import cStringIO
import SunRiseSet_Lendersdorf

#verschiedene Kameraeinstellungen fuer tag und nacht
FTEMP_DCAM = "/run/shm/img.jpg"
CAPT_UTIL   = "raspistill"  
CAPT_DCAM_DAY   = " -t 500 --ISO 200 -w 1600 -h 1200 -ex auto -o " + FTEMP_DCAM
CAPT_DCAM_NIGHT = " -t 500 --ISO 800 -w 1600 -h 1200 -ex night -o " + FTEMP_DCAM

try:
    os.remove(FTEMP_DCAM)
except OSError:
    pass

# Aktuelle Zeit, Sonnenauf-und Untergangszeit bestimmen
lt = time.localtime()
ActHour  = float(time.strftime("%H" , lt))
ActMin   = float(time.strftime("%M" , lt))
ActHour  = ActHour + ActMin/60.
RiseHour = SunRiseSet_Lendersdorf.GetLendersdorfSunRiseOrSet ( 1 )
SetHour  = SunRiseSet_Lendersdorf.GetLendersdorfSunRiseOrSet ( 0 )

# Zugriff mitloggen
#f = open('SNAP_ACCESS.TXT', 'a')
#f.write(time.strftime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%s",lt))
#f.write('\r\n')
#f.close()


try:
    if ActHour > RiseHour and ActHour < SetHour:
        error = subprocess.check_output(CAPT_UTIL+CAPT_DCAM_DAY, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        #print "DayTime"
    else:  
        error = subprocess.check_output(CAPT_UTIL+CAPT_DCAM_NIGHT, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        #print "NightTime"
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    #print "CalledProcessError" 
    pass

sys.stdout.write( "Content-Type: image/jpeg;\n\n" + file(FTEMP_DCAM,"rb").read() )
```

Comment: Lighttpd runs with uid=www-data, gid=www-data. So wherever you write temporary files (unless you use /tmp), you need to add www-data (userid) or www-data (group) to the access permissions.

Comment: yes, may be I do not understand the "ls -la" output correct
is the owner "root" and the group "www-data" ?

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -la /run/shm

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data 8 Apr 27 12:18 /run/shm -> /dev/shm


the directory is now empty

Comment: I tested with "/tmp" directory instead of "/run/shm." then I get a "Server Error 500" from the web browser. if i run the script manually as user "pi" it runs correct,meaning the old temp. file will be deleted, new file created by raspistill and the output is printed on the terminal.
I think there is some access right problem

Comment: I have to correct one comment: If the web server runs the python script, the img.jpg is not created. I think during my tries running the script with user "pi" it was "left over". This means the img.jpg cannot be created and not deleted.